# What does it mean? (Decoding newswires back to text)

Tags: python, keras

I can't understand this line

```
decoded_newswire = ''.join([reverse_word_index.get(i-3,'?') for i in train_data[0]])
```

in

```
from keras.datasets import reuters

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = reuters.load_data(num_words=10000)

word_index = reuters.get_word_index()

reverse_word_index = dict([(value,key)for(key,value)inword_index.items())

decoded_newswire = ''.join([reverse_word_index.get(i-3,'?') for i in train_data[0]])
```

Comment: What about it don't you understand? What it does?

Answer (score 0):

That line gets the loaded data, then iterates through it, reversing the index of the words through a dictionary that the dataset is returning, but for some reason, 3 from the last word. No idea what this is supposed to do, so some context would be great. Expected output, purpose, etc...